# Emergency phone number detection

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

How can I detect emergency phone number like 100, 101 etc using `UITextview`?

Links,PhoneNumber property is enabled in my `storyBoard`.

I also tried following code.

```
Mytextview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Comment: Mytextview.selectable = YES; try this one

Comment: i already  set this but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
self.myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

And if you want to detect the phone number then,

The textview should not be editable when you use `dataDetectorTypes`

Suppose,txtView be an object for `UITextView`, then do like:

```
textView.editable = NO;
```